# Which anime did the pregnancy test meme come from?

Tags: meme

Several months back, there was a meme circulating where anime characters had pregnancy tests photoshopped onto a picture of them.

Some examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The two hands and device look fairly well drawn, so I presume it was cut out from another show. I haven't been able to find out what **the show that originally had the pregnancy test** was. Does anyone know?

Comment: The two hands might not have come from the same source. The slight difference in skin tone suggests they came from different characters at least.

Comment: I suggest you to look at [this page](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/pregnancy-announcement) if you haven't already did.

Comment: @Dario, you should post that as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably from the original ending of Danna ga Nani o Itteiru ka Wakaranai Ken (Season 1 Episode 13), which aired in 2014.

A clip of the scene can be seen here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YU5CFBRL1R0

Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is actually convincing, but apparently, [season 1 episode 13 was broadcasted in December 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Can't_Understand_What_My_Husband_Is_Saying#Season_1), *2 months after* the October's trend on Twitter... now that I think about it, perhaps the meme *might* be started from its manga version instead?

Comment: Maybe. Crunchyroll got the license and started putting up episodes on 4 October, about a week before the blank image first showed up, so chances are someone saw the episode pre-release. The actual blank template was not cut from the episode, and the art style of the manga is quite rough, but I'l bet it is what started the wheels spinning in some jokester's head.

Answer (score 3):

Closest I could get to an answer.

According to [knowyourmeme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/pregnancy-announcement):

> According to archived discussions<sup>[[1]](http://imgbako.com/256387646.htm) [[2]](http://kmlg.jp/logview/kmlg.jp/archive/may_b/284333605.htm/index.htm)</sup> from the Japanese imageboard site Futaba Channel (2chan), the photoshop meme originally began as a minor fad sometime in the summer of 2014, but it didn’t take off until the blank template image was posted on Twitter<sup>[[4]](https://twitter.com/Gorxxx_/status/522386028594618369)</sup> by @Gorxxx_<sup>[[3]](https://twitter.com/Gorxxx_/)</sup> on October 15th, 2014."

Comment: It's a pity the user doesn't exist anymore :( might have been able to help